# Xamarin Pull down for searchbar

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, renderer

I'm working on an Cross Platform Project on VS 2015 with Xamarin. Android and iOS.
Want to make a renderer which will make searchbar visible when user scrolls up like whatsapp.

I created an renderer like this for Android.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
                return;
            var tableView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
            tableView.ScrollStateChanged += TableView_ScrollStateChanged;
        }

        private void TableView_ScrollStateChanged(object sender, Android.Widget.AbsListView.ScrollStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tableView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
            var asdf = tableView.OverScrollMode;
            var sss = tableView.ScrollIndicators;
            //int asdf1 = tableView.MaxScrollAmount;
            //int asdf2 = tableView.ScrollX;
            //int asdf3 = tableView.ScrollY;
        }
```

But I couldn't get the index of the rows who have been seen on phone.

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question.

Comment: @Jason sorry I was continue to writing.

Answer (score 0):

> But I couldn't get the index of the rows who have been seen on phone.

Based on your code, I guess that you are customizing a `TableView`, and your problem is how to get notified if it is scrolled to the end.

Then you can for example code like this:

```
public class MyTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer, IOnScrollListener
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
            return;
        var tableView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
        tableView.SetOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        //if last item is shown.
        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount)
            Log.Debug("item", totalItemCount.ToString());
    }

    public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, [GeneratedEnum] ScrollState scrollState)
    {
    }
}
```